# Including multiple columns in NOT IN

Tags: sql, insert

I have two tables as below.

Table 1

```
Book price
A   100
B   200
C   400
D   300
```

Table 2

```
Book price
A   100
B   200
C   400
```

Now I am executing below command as I want only the 4th record to get inserted into table 2. I want to add both the column names before NOT IN. what should I do?

```
Insert into table2 select * from table1 t1 where t1.book not in (select book from table2);
```

Comment: have you tried out instead of "not in" , where t1.book <> t2.book?

Comment: So when you run it as a `select` without the `insert` do you see the row you expect?

Comment: I tried your code, it is working for me, good to know it is working now

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` along with matching the presumably primary key columns `Book` for both of the tables such as

```sql
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t1 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM table2 WHERE Book=t1.Book);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=338941cb7e93a63120f7366994c2ffe1)</kbd>

P.S.: Should be careful about ***NULL*** values while using `NOT IN` operator. Moreover, using `NOT IN` is mostly less performant than using `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @Barbaros9Özhan No this is not working because the other rows exist in the 2nd table.

Comment: @Kavya14 have you checked out the demo ?

Comment: @Barbaros9Özhan Yes I understood it now. This will work. Thanks

Comment: @Barbaros9Özhan can you please tell me if I can add more than one column before not in and how?

Comment: @Kavya14 indeed your current case would do what you want with the current data, but the problem would arise for the NULL values through use of `NOT NULL` such as within [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0cf07789e3b866a7c9a92e71fdf173b2). I think you ask help for this point...

Comment: @Barbaros9Özhan ok but how do I do it with this data?

Comment: [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=32b74ae770fe64f2b0817dd88d7819e8) which's not different than your original case... @Kavya14

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and it looks fine to me.

may be you run the script twice so it will show `0 rows created` in the second time.

make sure you `committed` the row.

[image]

Comment: Yes it's working now. I must have made some mistake the first time. Thanks. Can you also tell me how can I use 2 columns before not in?

Comment: try this one `Insert into table2 select * from table1 t1 where (t1.book, t1.price) not in (select book, price from table2);`

Comment: It's giving error as 'Type IN must have only one output'

Comment: what database you are working on? and what is DB version?

Comment: I am working in bigquery

Comment: [Bigquery error - Subquery of type IN must have only one output column](https://copycoding.com/d/bigquery-error-subquery-of-type-in-must-have-only-one-output-column)

Comment: thanks a lot!! It worked.